# Композиция в Java

Tags: java

Нужен легкий и простой пример использования композиции в коде Java. 
Сам принцип использования готовых объектов других классов в новом классе понятен, а вот с реализацией в коде не могу разобраться.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=java+composition+example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=WMahVNmSI6afygPErICQCw

Первая же ссылка.

Comment: @stanilin, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.